# Rounding results in highcharts jquery script

Tags: jquery, highcharts, rounding

I know this is a bit out there... but gonna ask anyways. I'm using highcharts jquery script (http://www.highcharts.com/) to generate a pie chart. I am trying to round off the number results in the pie chart and cannot find any documentation to do so. I'm stuck!

My data looks something like this:

```
data: [
    ['Equity',   3],
    ['Cash',     6]
]
```

And the pie chart outputs:
33.333333333333
and
66.666666666666

I'd rather get the results rounded up and down respectively so it reads and shows 33 and 64. Does anyoone know how this can be set up in highcharts?

Comment: why don't you try to round the input data, the app will try to complete the data because it has to sum 100.

Comment: I don't have control of the data, otherwise I would ensure the numbers would equal 100 before being fed to highcharts.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In in the tooltip option in the configuration object use Math.round() in the formatter function.

```
   tooltip: {
     formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
     }
  },
```

Answer (score 31):

```
tooltip: {
  valueDecimals: 2
},
```

Comment: Thanks for thanks for this. I found this the easiest way to get something incredibly customized already to easily have the 2 decimal places. No more formatter crazyiness

Comment: This works, but the problem here is that even .00 will appear. For example: 25.00

Answer (score 22):

There's a `numberFormat`function available in the Highcharts API that you can use (see http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#highcharts-object).

Quoted from API doc:

**numberFormat** (Number number, [Number decimals], [String decimalPoint], [String thousandsSep]) : String

Formats a JavaScript number with grouped thousands, a fixed amount of decimals and an optional decimal point. It is a port of PHP's function with the same name. See PHP number_format for a full explanation of the parameters.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return ''+ this.series.name +''+
            this.x +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, ',') +' millions';
    }
}, ...
```

#### Parameters

- number: Number
  The raw number to format.
- decimals: Number
  The desired number of decimals.
- decimalPoint: String
  The decimal point. Defaults to "." or to the string specified globally in options.lang.decimalPoint.
- thousandsSep: String
  The thousands separator. Defaults to "," or to the string specified globally in options.lang.thousandsSep.

#### Returns

A string with with the input number formatted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went with the other answer as it was a much simpler solution. Just wanted to let you know I saw your solution as well!

Comment: I like this solution because sometimes i need to round to certain number of decimal digist.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of use `formatter` you can set `yDecimals` as `2`:

```
tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
}
```

**yDecimals**: `Number`
`How many decimals to show in each series' y value. This is overridable in each series' tooltip options object. The default is to preserve all decimals.`

Answer (score 4):

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 +' %';
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
percentageDecimals: 0
```

in your tooltip